# Disallow mpi4py to interfere with internal handling of mpi by a python API

Tags: mpi, hpc, mpi4py, zarr, nest-simulator

I am using `mpiexec` on a cluster to run large-scale simulations using [pyNEST](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3/ref_material/pynest_apis.html) (`mpiexec -n $N python simulate.py`). I export a large number of small files which often tends to exceed my inode quota on the cluster. So, I am trying to reduce the number of exported files by allowing only one of the MPI processes ("mother") to export by `gather()`-ing the data of interest. Theoretically, this works fine. However, when I try this on `pyNEST (v2.20.2)` just `import mpi4py` (implicit call to `MPI.Init()`) interferes with the internal mpi handling mechanism of `pyNEST` API. Somehow, instead of receiving `N` processes, only one mpi process is received by the API---which crashes the kernel because it expects `N` processes (you have to explicitly specify `N` in your `pyNEST` code).

**Is there a way to prevent mpi4py from interfering with the API's internal mpi mech?**

**Alternatively, can you suggest a file format that supports parallel writes?**
I've looked into `zarr`, however, parallel zarr writes are only optimal if the chunk size are uniform. In my case, the chunk size (data exported per mpi process) are never uniform. Sometimes their length differ by more than 10x and I cannot predict what the chunk sizes will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the implicit `MPI_Init`:

```
import mpi4py
mpi4py.rc.initialize = False
mpi4py.rc.finalize = False
from mpi4py import MPI
```

and then you need to Init/Finalize explicitly, or I guess have them done by PyNest.

File I/O: MPI has its own parallel file I/O. Alternatively, check out hdf5 for a very popular system.